# How do I move the cursor to the beginning of the line in VSCode's terminal?

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code, zsh

I have my terminal set to zsh, and in iTerm2 I can press `ctrl+e` to move my cursor to the end of the line, and `ctrl+a` to move to the beginning. In VSCode, this just prints out a literal `^E^A`. Is there a setting I need to allow terminal to respond to emacs style commands?

Comment: Wow... I feel really dumb. I've been wondering how to get this working for the longest time, because none of the below answers work for me. Turns out I just needed to add `bindkey -e` to my .zshrc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As was mentioned in a comment above:

Open `~/.zshrc`, and add this line to the end:

```
bindkey -e
```

I'm unclear why this works automatically for zsh in iTerm, but must be manually set to work with zsh in VSCode.

Answer (score 6):

Try these keybindings:

```
  {
    "key": "ctrl+e",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
    "args": { "text": "\u0005" },   // move cursor to end of line, sends ctrl+e to terminal
    "when": "terminalFocus"
  },
  
  {
    "key": "ctrl+a",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
    "args": { "text": "\u0001" },   // move cursor to start of line, sends ctrl+a to terminal
    "when": "terminalFocus"
  },
```

Works in bash, I can't test in zsh but it should work.

Answer (score 4):

Try starting Visual Studio Code from iTerm2 using `code`.

That did it for me on... <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd> and <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>right</kbd> work as expected.

Very strange though... opened an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/80018).

Comment: Do you know how to do that with linux?. In my case ubuntu Binonic 18.04.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have zsh, but you may have luck with either the [`cursorHome` and `cursorEnd`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings) commands or the `workbench.action.terminal.moveToLineStart` and `workbench.action.terminal.moveToLineEnd` commands. Both can be set in either keyboard shortcuts or keybindings.json in the Command Palette - `ctrl+shift+p` then search 'keyboard shortcuts'

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn’t appear to work when using the zsh shell.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **View**, **Command Palette**, then search and select **Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts**.

Now search for `cursorLineStart` and give a keybinding shortcut to it i.e., `Ctrl + DownArrow`. Similarly you can use `cursorLineEnd` to move the caret to the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

###### For Emacs mode users

@[Adrian Macneil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/462702/adrian-macneil)'s answer works.

`–e` Binds all keys to the standard GNU Emacs-like bindings.

[bindkey built-in command for tcsh: List all bound keys | IBM](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.1.0?topic=scd-bindkey-built-in-command-tcsh-list-all-bound-keys)

###### For vi mode users

Set the following 2 lines to your *~/.zshrc*.

```
bindkey "^a" vi-beginning-of-line
bindkey "^e" vi-end-of-line
```

Make sure `bindkey` lines are placed **after** `zle` commands.

---

Sorry that I don't have enough reputation to add comment under his thread.